# Nodejs: Sequelize and Promises - not really working async as expected

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

Just when I thought I understood Promises, some code shows me the opposite.
I have an array with a (big) result from a database query (using Sequelize).

What I want to do is loop the results and for each row I want to insert some data into another database table. When the last insert is done, I want to return a promise so my (sync) chain of commands can continue.

```
// above ^ is code for retrieving results from db
.then(function (results) {
    return Promise.map(results, function(row) {
        log.info('Handle ' + row.file);

        // Images is a sequelize model defined above
        return Images.create({
            id: row.image_id,
            file: row.image_original_source
        }).then(function() {
            log.info('DB insert for ' + row.id);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            log.error(err);
        });
    });
})
.then(function (results) {
// continue the chain when all Images are made
```

I would expect that as soon as the loop starts then Images.create would start inserting into the database.

Instead the code waits until all the results are looped through and only then starts to insert stuff to database. This is easy to see when results has 10k+ elements. All the "Handle " logging is output, and only then "DB insert for " starts being output.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Looks like http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html#map-option-concurrency might be of use to you.

Comment: This is an inefficient way to load lots of rows into a database.  At the very least you should use bulkCreate (http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance) or better yet, a streaming input into your database.  If you use MySQL, save your data to a file and then load it in with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE`, or if you use PostgreSQL, look into node-pg-copy-streams (https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams).  Also, I made a library for this purpose: https://github.com/djstroky/db-streamer

Comment: @KevinB Thanks! That made the code do exactly what I expected. I'm a bit amazed this is not the default behavior.

Comment: @DJStroky That might be true, though the loading part is not the problem here, that goes relatively fast. I'm aware of mysql_dump and the likes, but that is not actually the right tool for me in this case. BulkCreate, great tip, I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: The code you posted does not have properly matching closing brace and parens before the last `.then()`.  I'm not sure if that's part of your real code or just a copy/paste issue in your question.

Comment: @Fractalf you're firing off a ton of operations and sequelize tries to execute them all at once which is slow. Throttling like KevinB suggested might be a viable option.

Comment: @DJStroky I missread your comment in my first reply above. You are very right, loading _into_ db this way was not good at all. I found that the concurrency option solved the problem though, where I can choose how may inserts to do before the next bulk.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I updated the code above. This was just a typo though and not directly relevant to my actual problem.

Comment: It's still inefficient, almost always a bad idea to send a sql query in a loop.

Comment: @KevinB Can you elaborate, what are the alternatives? How would you else insert a large array of db-objects if not loop through them? In this case I have BulkCreate, but if I wanted to do this with just SQL?

Comment: Create one giant insert string. This would prevent needing to send so many requests to/from the database.